# What is an EUAP Region in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Some regions in Azure are referred to as EUAP regions, however I am unable to find any kind of definition as to what this means. What does EUAP stand for?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.locationnames.centraluseuap?view=azure-dotnet

From the link above:

> Name of the Azure Central US EUAP region in the Azure Cosmos DB service.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

EUAP stands for Early Updates Access Program. These are special canary regions in Azure:

- Central US EUAP
- East US 2 EUAP

Comment: I believe a source would be great here, although it is only a comment a s a note here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validate-service-updates

Comment: More information was added to the page you linked to, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validate-service-updates#what-is-the-azure-safe-deployment-practices-framework so that could be considered an official source