# Cosmos DB v2 SDK PreferredLocations Property

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We are trying to use the Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ConnectionPolicy.PreferredLocations property as per this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-global-distribution-sql-api?tabs=dotnetv2%2Capi-async#net-sdk to use additional read regions for CosmosDB calls from our service.
The Read Location is “East US 2 EUAP” and the write location is “Central US EUAP”.
But all the read requests go to only the write location instead of the read location.
Is “East US 2 EUAP”  a valid value for the PreferredLocations property?
I’m using the same string as that shown on the portal (enabled under read regions). The documentation mentions regions on this https://azure.microsoft.com/regions/ but there is nothing mentioned for “EUAP” regions. As per the documentation, I believe this is what is happening

```
If the read regions specified in the PreferredLocations list are not available, reads will be served out of write region.
```

Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like EUAP regions relate to [early access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50647007/what-is-an-euap-region-in-azure). You can specify them with the [LocationNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.locationnames?view=azure-dotnet) class. That said, I'm not sure on current status -- it seems like a better idea to use the public regions unless you have a specific need for EUAP.